# Printing table cells from right to left

Tags: html, css, html-table, right-to-left

I make a table and want the first cell to start from right instead of from left as default.
I tried changing the float attribute in CSS but it doesn't seem to help. 
Here is the code:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="result_table">
    <tr align="right">
    <th bgcolor="#cccccc" align="right">1</th>
    <th bgcolor="#cccccc" size="17">2</th>
    <th bgcolor="#cccccc">3</th>
    <th bgcolor="#cccccc">4</th>
    </tr>

</table>

<style>
    table.result_table {
        float:right;
    }
</style>
```

Can anyone suggest a way to change the float of this table?

Comment: what do you want to change from right? the content of first cell?

Comment: Why don't you use `direction:ltr;` for the cell?

Comment: change table direction to `rtl` insted of `float`

Comment: thanks the rtl worked perfectly.!

Answer (score 17):

As suggested in comments, you can set directionality to right-to-left (RTL). However, unless your table content is in a right-to-left language, you should additionally set the directionality in table content elements to left-to-right. Otherwise, they inherit RTL directionality, which will cause surprises in many situations, since the directionality also sets the overall text directionality. This will not affect normal text in a Western language, but it will affect e.g. content like “4 (5)”, which would appear as “(5) 4” with RTL directionality.

Thus, you should set

```
table.result_table {
  direction: rtl; }
table.result_table caption, table.result_table th, table.result_table td {
  direction: ltr; }
```

Comment: I had to do the opposite, but that was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is a much easier way. You can add `dir="rtl"` to the table.

```
<table dir="rtl">
     ...
</table>
```

Or you can use CSS instead of using HTML attribute:

```
<table style="direction:rtl">
     ...
</table>
```

Comment: The easy one! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be achieved with CSS only. If using jQuery is Ok for you, here's a starting idea that might get you to the desired result:

CSS:

```
.result_table{float:left; width:100%; border-collapse:collapse; padding:0;}
.result_table th{float:right; padding:0;}
```

JS:

```
var cols = $('.result_table th').length;
var colWidth = 100 / cols;
$('.result_table th').css({width:colWidth+'%'})
```

Example - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YhzN5/)

Comment: thank you for your comment, but the rtl worked perfectly for me.