# responsive email stacking tables

Tags: html, email, responsive

I am working with the new responsive templates in dotmailer and all elements are now block tables, there are no multi-column tables. I want to stack a right table element over a left table element in a responsive environment while keeping the left/right arrangement on the desktop.

Here is the code for the full element I am working in

I have tried creating the element as a table with columns but cannot save the file when I do that, I have tried css with floats on table ids, the tables, td, and inline css, some of this configurations would flip the order on desktop not a phone. (I am looking specificaly at iphone6)

Is it possible to flip the stacking on block elements?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" class="row two-cols ee_columns ee_element" ee-type="container" data-title="2 columns" style="position: relative; background-color: rgb(174, 184, 194);">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center" valign="top" class="row-inner f-size-0 element-pad" dir="ltr" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;"><!--[if mso]><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:650px;" width="650" class="mso-table-width"><tr><td align="left" valign="top" style="width:331px;" width="320" class="mso-column-width"><![endif]-->
                                        <!-- STACK COLUMN : BEGIN -->
                                        <div class="stack-column stack-column-width" ee-percent-width="51" style="max-width: 50.92%; min-width: 331px; width: 650px;" id="right-stack">
                                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="stack_bottom">
                                            <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td dir="rlt" class="col-inner ee_dropzone" align="left"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="col-font-reset ee_element" ee-type="element">
                                                  <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td align="left" class="element-pad element-bord" style="padding: 0px;"><img src="img" alt="" style="width: 100%; display: block; height: auto;" class="ee_editable  vedpw331" ee-width="331" border="0" width="331" /></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </tbody>
                                                </table></td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- STACK COLUMN : END -->
                                        <!--[if mso]></td><td align="left" valign="top" style="width:325px;" width="325" class="column"><![endif]-->
                                        <!-- STACK COLUMN : BEGIN -->
                                        <div class="stack-column stack-column-width" ee-percent-width="49" style="max-width: 49.07%; min-width: 319px; width: 650px;" id="left-stack">
                                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="stack_top">
                                            <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td dir="ltr" class="col-inner ee_dropzone" align="left"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ee_element ee_spacer col-font-reset" ee-type="element">
                                                  <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;"><img src="https://i.emlfiles.com/cmpimg/t/s.gif" style="display: block; width: 1px; height: 10px;" alt="" class="" border="0" width="1" height="10" /></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="col-font-reset ee_element" width="100%" ee-type="element">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top" align="left" class="element-pad element-bord"><div class="ee_editable">
                                                          <p class="h3" style="text-align: left; font-size: 17px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); line-height: 120%;"><b><a href="http://sidekickmag.com/dental-technology/digital-technology-delivers-excellence-in-same-day-restorations/?campaignkw=same_day&amp;_linkgroups=technology" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration: none;">Headline</a></b></p>
                                                        </div></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="col-font-reset ee_element" width="100%" ee-type="element">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top" align="left" class="element-pad element-bord"><div class="ee_editable">
                                                          <p style="font-size: 14px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); line-height: 120%;" class="col-text">Text elements here</p>
                                                        </div></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                                  <table style="max-width: 100%; position: relative; table-layout: auto;" class="row one-cols ee_columns ee_element" ee-type="container" data-title="Columns" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td class="row-inner f-size-0 element-pad col-inner" valign="top" align="center"><!--[if mso]><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:319px;" width="319" class="mso-table-width"><tr><td align="left" valign="top" style="width:319px;" width="330" class="mso-column-width"><![endif]-->
                                                          <!-- STACK COLUMN : BEGIN -->
                                                          <div class="no-stack-column no-stack-column-width" ee-percent-width="100">
                                                            <table style="table-layout: auto;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                              <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                  <td dir="ltr" class="col-inner ee_dropzone" align="left"><table style="max-width: 100%; position: relative; table-layout: auto;" class="row one-cols ee_columns ee_element" ee-type="container" data-title="Columns" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                      <tr>
                                                                        <td style="padding-top: 0px;padding-right: 20px;padding-bottom: 0px;padding-left: 20px;" class="row-inner f-size-0 element-pad col-inner" valign="top" align="center"><!--[if mso]><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:279px;" width="279" class="mso-table-width"><tr><td align="left" valign="top" style="width:279px;" width="290" class="mso-column-width"><![endif]-->
                                                                          <!-- STACK COLUMN : BEGIN -->
                                                                          <div class="no-stack-column no-stack-column-width" ee-percent-width="100">
                                                                            <table style="table-layout: auto;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                                              <tbody>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                  <td dir="ltr" class="col-inner ee_dropzone" align="left"><table class="ee_element ee_spacer col-font-reset" ee-type="element" style="table-layout: auto;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                                      <tr>
                                                                                        <td style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;"><img src="https://i.emlfiles.com/cmpimg/t/s.gif" style="display: block; width: 1px; height: 20px;" alt="" class="" width="1" border="0" height="20" /></td>
                                                                                      </tr>
                                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                                  </table>
                                                                                    <table style="max-width: 100%; position: relative; table-layout: auto;" class="row one-cols ee_columns ee_element" ee-type="container" data-title="Columns" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
                                                                                      <tbody>
                                                                                        <tr>
                                                                                          <td style="padding-top: 0px;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;padding-left: 0px;" class="row-inner f-size-0 element-pad col-inner" valign="top" align="center"><!--[if mso]><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:279px;" width="279" class="mso-table-width"><tr><td align="left" valign="top" style="width:279px;" width="290" class="mso-column-width"><![endif]-->
                                                                                            <!-- STACK COLUMN : BEGIN -->
                                                                                            <div class="no-stack-column no-stack-column-width" ee-percent-width="100">
                                                                                              <table style="table-layout: auto;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                                                                <tbody>
                                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                                    <td style="background-color: rgb(218, 222, 227);" dir="ltr" class="col-inner ee_dropzone" align="left"><table class="col-font-reset ee_element" ee-type="element" style="table-layout: auto;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                                                      <tbody>
                                                                                                        <tr>
                                                                                                          <td class="element-pad element-bord" valign="top" align="left"><div class="ee_editable">
                                                                                                            <p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: 17px; color: rgb(83, 169, 172);"><b>Text Button</b></p>
                                                                                                          </div></td>
                                                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                                      </tbody>
                                                                                                    </table></td>
                                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                                </tbody>
                                                                                              </table>
                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                            <!-- STACK COLUMN : END -->
                                                                                            <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
                                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                      </tbody>
                                                                                    </table></td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                              </tbody>
                                                                            </table>
                                                                          </div>
                                                                          <!-- STACK COLUMN : END -->
                                                                          <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
                                                                      </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                  </table>
                                                                    <table class="ee_element ee_spacer col-font-reset" ee-type="element" style="table-layout: auto;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                                      <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                          <td style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;"><img src="https://i.emlfiles.com/cmpimg/t/s.gif" style="display: block; width: 1px; height: 10px;" alt="" class="" width="1" border="0" height="10" /></td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                      </tbody>
                                                                    </table></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                              </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                          </div>
                                                          <!-- STACK COLUMN : END -->
                                                          <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                  </table></td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- STACK COLUMN : END -->
                                        <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Comment: Your dropbox link is not viewable. Please replace it with a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), or similar.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of achieving this:

**Method 1:** I've found that the simplest way to achieve a reverse stack in email is to code your two columns into `<th>` tags, then with a class style the header cells to display as `table-footer` and `table-header` respectively.

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
    .w320{ width:320px; }
    .thg{ display: table-header-group !important; width:100% !important; font-weight:normal;}
    .tfg{ display: table-footer-group !important; width:100% !important; font-weight:normal;}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="w320" bgcolor="#333333">
        <tr>
            <th class="tfg" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                <table width="100%" class="w320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>left</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </th>
            <th class="thg" bgcolor="#999999">
                <table width="100%" class="w320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>right</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Method 2:** If keeping your content in block tables is important to you then you could use the below method. The tables are declared with the right table before the left and reordered using the direction style. This method will require VML to keep then inline on Outlook 2007, 10 and 13.

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
    .w320{ width:320px; }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="w320">
        <tr>
            <td style="direction:rtl">
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="direction:rtl">
                <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                <![endif]-->
                <table width="280" class="w320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display:inline" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                    <tr>
                        <td>right</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                <![endif]-->
                <table width="280" class="w320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display:inline" bgcolor="#999999">
                    <tr>
                        <td>left</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This method will require VML to keep then inline on Outlook 2007, 10 and 13. Is there a resource for the VML?

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293808/printing-table-cells-from-right-to-left) addresses reordering cells using the direction style. You can use this on the VML table which contains the two nested tables.

Comment: @RoseLanaro  I've added an edit to my answer to include VML in method 2. Please mark as accepted if this helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to be the solution, there must be some conflict with the dotmailer coding. I removed their VML code for this element but that still did not swith the stacking